# Error in association or containment

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

This is one of those times when I know I'm doing something wrong, but I'm apparently deaf, dumb and blind with respect to seeing it. I'm hoping that another pair of eyes can open my own.

I have a `ZipCode` model and an `Incentive` model. There is a glorified join table (glorified because it has its own key) sitting in the middle. The join table has `id`, `incentive_id` and `zip` fields (legacy database). My `ZipCode` model HABTM `Incentive` as shown:

```
  public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Incentive' => array(
    'with'                  => 'ZipCodeIncentive',
    'foreignKey'            => 'zip',
    'associationForeignKey' => 'incentive_id',
  ),
);
```

My `Incentive` model HABTM `ZipCode` as follows:

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
  'ZipCode' => array(
    'with'                  => 'ZipCodeIncentive',
    'foreignKey'            => 'incentive_id',
    'associationForeignKey' => 'zip',
),
```

I have a method, `ZipCode::incentives( $zip )` that wants to pull all of the incentives relevant to the specified zip code:

```
$incentives = $this->Incentive->find(
  'all',
  array(
    'contain'    => array( 'ZipCode' ),
    'fields'     => array( 'Incentive.id', 'Incentive.name', 'Incentive.it_name', 'Incentive.amount', 'Incentive.state', 'Incentive.entire_state', 'Incentive.excluded', 'Incentive.is_active' ),
    'conditions' => array(
      'Incentive.excluded'  => 0,
      'Incentive.is_active' => 1,
      'OR' => array(
        'Incentive.state' => 'US',  # nationwide incentives
        array(
          # Incentives that apply to the entire state the zip code belongs to
          'Incentive.entire_state' => 1,
          'Incentive.state'        => $state,
        ),
        'ZipCode.zip' => $zip # specific to the building's zip code
      )
    ),
    'order' => array( 'Incentive.amount DESC' ),
  )
);
```

What I get for my trouble is the following error:

```
SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'ZipCode.zip' in 'where clause'
```

The `ZipCode` model's table isn't getting joined in the SQL, but I haven't grasped *why* yet. It's worth mentioning that the `Incentive` model is tied to a **MySql view**, not a table, via `$useTable`. I haven't seen anything to suggest that it should be a problem in this scenario, but it's non-standard.

If you see what I'm missing, please call 911 or at least drop an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rob

Move the condition

```
  'ZipCode.zip' => $zip
```

To your contain declaration like this

```
 array(
    'contain' => array( 'ZipCode'=> 
                            array('conditions'=>
                                  array('ZipCode.zip' => $zip ))),
```

Then continue with the rest of your statement as usual

Comment: Doh! I knew it was going to be something like that. Not quite as obvious as I half-expected it to be, but I appreciate your help. That's been smoking my bags for the better part of the day. I'd mark your answer twice if SO would let me do that.